# How to anchor specific ID in code from markdown in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I have a markdown in my project as content catalog of the project.
I wish to write something like code below, And it may anchor to specific **id** in code.

```markdown
<!-- markdown -->
[feat name](/path/to/file#someId)
```

```
// code
// some ID/anchor that can link to
```

When use cmd+click, vscode can redirect to right location.

Comment: you might use `vscode:` scheme links that can contain line numbers, what kind if file is this code file

Comment: @rioV8 I know that 'path/to/file#l20' would link to line 20. But I don't wanna use line, because line might easily changed.